# ExecuteNonQuery() returning 1 without any updates or without affecting

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am checking how many rows were affected in database tables.

Here is my code :

```
Try
    Dim RowsAffected As Integer
    con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
    con.Open()
    Dim cb As String = "update Hostel set HostelName='" & txtHostelName.Text & "', address='" & txtAddress.Text & "',Phone='" & txtPhoneNo.Text & "',ManagedBy='" & txtManagedBy.Text & "',contactno='" & txtContactNo.Text & "' where hostelname= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)
    cmd.Connection = con
    RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If RowsAffected > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        MsgBox("The no.of rows affected by update query are " & RowsAffected.ToString)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No changes were made", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    btnUpdate_record.Enabled = False
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

Comment: Why do you think there is no update? Are you sure you passed the correct key and did you check the data before and after the update?

Comment: yeah without any updates its returning 1

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: an update could occur without the data change, for example if you pass the same data that was in the row, but still this counts as an update. If you have a trigger on the table, and that trigger updates other rows, it would still get you a positive value.